# How to find the event handler for a DispatcherTimer in windbg

Tags: silverlight-3.0, windbg

I have a Silverlight 3 application which seems to be leaking DispatcherTimer objects. At least, over time when the application runs I find more of them on the heap:

!dumpheap -type DispatcherTimer

returns an increating number of them.

I'd like to find the Tick event handler method for these so I can identify where they're created in my code.

When I try dumping one of these in windbg, I get something like:

```
!do 098b9980
Name:        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
MethodTable: 0bfd4ba0
EEClass:     0bc98d18
Size:        20(0x14) bytes
File:        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.50524.0\System.Windows.dll
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
0bfd1538  40008be        4 ...eObjectSafeHandle  0 instance 098b9994 m_nativePtr
0bfd3d0c  40008bf        8 ...reTypeEventHelper  0 instance 098b99ac _coreTypeEventHelper
506a07e4  40008c0        c       System.Boolean  1 instance        1 _isEnabled
0bfd3c68  40008c1      cec ...ependencyProperty  0   shared   static IntervalProperty
    >> Domain:Value  086d3f38:NotInit  086daeb8:098b99b8 <<
```

But from here, I don't know how to find the method handling the Tick event. I suspect it's something to do with _coreTypeEventHelper, but when I dump that, I get:

```
!do 098b99ac 
Name:        MS.Internal.CoreTypeEventHelper
MethodTable: 0bfd3d0c
EEClass:     0bc98420
Size:        12(0xc) bytes
File:        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.50524.0\System.Windows.dll
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
00000000  40009f5        4                       0 instance 098b9ae4 _eventAndDelegateTable
506a0e94  40009f4      514         System.Int32  1   shared   static _nextAvailableTableIndex
    >> Domain:Value  086d3f38:NotInit  086daeb8:669 <<
```

then I dump the _eventAndDelegateTable:

```
Name:        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib],[MS.Internal.CoreTypeEventHelper+EventAndDelegate, System.Windows]]
MethodTable: 0bfcc0a0
EEClass:     5026c744
Size:        52(0x34) bytes
File:        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.50524.0\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
5068f2d0  4000648        4       System.Int32[]  0 instance 098b9b18 buckets
50691060  4000649        8 ...non, mscorlib]][]  0 instance 098b9b30 entries
506a0e94  400064a       20         System.Int32  1 instance        1 count
506a0e94  400064b       24         System.Int32  1 instance        1 version
506a0e94  400064c       28         System.Int32  1 instance       -1 freeList
506a0e94  400064d       2c         System.Int32  1 instance        0 freeCount
50697f08  400064e        c ...Int32, mscorlib]]  0 instance 098b9650 comparer
506ccfb0  400064f       10 ...Canon, mscorlib]]  0 instance 00000000 keys
506ceaac  4000650       14 ...Canon, mscorlib]]  0 instance 00000000 values
506a02e4  4000651       18        System.Object  0 instance 00000000 _syncRoot
506895d8  4000652       1c ...SerializationInfo  0 instance 00000000 m_siInfo
```

And then I'm kind of lost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before attempting to find the relevant event handler, you could also search for the source of the leak by investigating why the `DispatcherTimer` instances doesn't get released.
After you have the output of the `!dumpheap -type DispatcherTimer`, execute the `!gcroot` command on a couple of instances of `DispatcherTimer`. You should be able to see which object holds a reference to the timer.
Also, you could place appropriate breakpoints (using `!bpmd`), in order to obtain helpful stacktraces.